# Styling Mui DatePicker's year picker : font size is too small

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, font-size

I have trouble styling MUI's DatePicker, especially the Year Picker.

I tried styling the component two ways :

#### Method 1 : with the help of MUI's createTheme() :

```
  MuiYearPicker: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        fontFamily: "Cabin",
        color: `${colors.primary}`,
        fontSize: "1rem",
      },
    },
  },
  PrivatePickersYear: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        fontFamily: "Cabin",
        color: `${colors.primary}`,
        fontSize: "1rem",
      },
    },
  },
```

#### Method 2 : styling the DatePicker's Poppers props by providing it with sx props :

```
const popperSx: SxProps = {
    "& .MuiPaper-root": {
      color: colors.primary,
      fontSize: "1.2rem",
      fontFamily: "Cabin",
    },
    "& .MuiCalendarPicker-root": {
      color: colors.primary,
      fontSize: "1.2rem",
      fontFamily: "Cabin",
    },
    "& .MuiPickersDay-dayWithMargin": {
      color: colors.primary,
      fontSize: "1.2rem",
      fontFamily: "Cabin",
    },
    "& .MuiYearPicker-root": {
      color: colors.primary,
      fontSize: "1.2rem",
      fontFamily: "Cabin",
    },
  };
```

However, even though the other parts of the DatePicker are getting styled (the date, the day picker), the year picker displays very small years :

[image: Here is the preview]

How can I custom its font size ?

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with it for some time. This is the solution.
In the SxProps:

```
'& .PrivatePickersYear-yearButton': {
        fontSize: '10px',
 },
```